# Why did Apache IoTDB reported `DriverTask is aborted by timeout` error when setting up?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I just set up the upgraded version of Apache IoTDB, and my server reported `301: DriverTask 20230516_075920_66555_1.1.0.4 is aborted by timeout`. I cannot understand the error information. Has anyone encountered this error? Which startup parameter should I adjust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the IP address in the configuration file needs to be modified. Check if your IP address is renewed to the upgraded version of Apache IoTDB.